# Let $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$, then $H$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

So this is a more general case of a well-known problem where $H$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is contained in every Sylow $p$-subgroup.

So, now, we do not have the option that it is normal.
I tried the same approach as when it is normal where I would the Second Sylow Theorem and show the containment within another group. But this doesn't work anymore because it is not normal anymore.

I also tried a different approach where $H$ is a fixed subgroup of $G$ and $A, B$ are any subgroups of $G$, a H-conjugacy class where $x\in H$, $B = x^{-1}Ax=\{x^{-1}ax:a \in A\}$

I thought I was going somewhere with the $H$-conjugacy class..
Would you provide a proof please?

Comment: Do you happen to know that the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups is $1\pmod p$? If yes, consider the action of $H$ on the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups by conjugation: $(h, S)\mapsto S^h$. Does it have fixed points? What do you know about $H\cdot S$ for a fixed point $S$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $X=\{Px : x \in G \}$ the set of right cosets of $P$ in $G$ and observe that $|X|=|G:P|$ is not divisible by $p$ since $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Now let act $H$ on $X$ by right multiplication. Since the lengths of the orbits divide the $p$-power $|H|$, and $|X|$ is not divisible by $p$, there must be at least one orbit of length $1$, say the orbit of $Pg$. Hence $Pgh=Pg$ for all $h \in H$, which is equivalent to $H \subseteq P^g$. And of course, $P^g$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup when $P$ is one.

Comment: Could you please explain what an orbit is?

Comment: Study this: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/group-actions-ii-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem/ and the first theorem mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest a less technical proof? For that let's define a Sylow $p$-subgroup as a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, i.e. $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ if for a $p$-subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $P \subset K$, it follows $P = K$.

Now if $H$ is $p$-subgroup of $G$ it is either properly contained in a $p$-subgroup or not. If it is not properly contained in a $p$-subgroup it is a Sylow $p$-subgroup by definition. Otherwise let $H^{\prime}$ be a $p$-subgroup which properly containes $H$, i.e. $H\subsetneq H^{\prime}$. Continuing in this way we get a sequence of $p$-subgroups:
$$H\subsetneq H^{\prime} \subsetneq H^{\prime \prime} \cdots,$$ which has to terminate since $G$ is finite.

Remark: Using Zorn's Lemma the same proof applies to infinite $G$.

Comment: You have to be careful here. The definition of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ is $|P|$ is a $p$-power and $|G:P|$ is not divisble by $p$.  Obviously, a Sylow $p$-subgroup in this sense is a maximal $p$-subgroup. But how to prove the converse? If $Q$ denotes the quaternion group of order $8$, it has a subgroup of index $2$, which is a maximal $2$-subgroup. Still the subgroup of order $4$ is not a Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and interesting thoughts. There are at least 4 equivalent definitions of Sylow $p$-subgroups, see e.g. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sylow_subgroup#Equivalent_definitions_in_tabular_format. Actually my defintion is more common in modern literature see e.g. Joseph J. Rotman, "Advanced Modern Algebra" page 269, or M. Artin, "Abstract Algebra". Also in your example $Q$ is the only  2-Sylow subgroup. You are refering probably to the cyclic maximal subgroup which is proper subgroup. In the definition of Sylow subgroups properness is not assumed.

Comment: Btw, your prove above is also very nice and short :)

Comment: @NickyHekster: JJR defined a $p$-Sylow subgroup (correctly) to be a subgroup maximal among the $p$-subgroups, not wrongly - like you understood - as maximal subgroup that happens to be a $p$-group.